# In Python, how can I create a dataframe from a list of lists?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to take a list of lists and transform it into a dataframe such that the dataframe has only one column and each sublist takes one row in the dataframe. Below is an image of what I have attempted, but each word within each sublist is being put in different columns.

[Current dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQyU8.png)

Essentially, I want a table that looks like this:
[How I want the dataframe to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OaLk5.png)

Comment: It would make it easier for people to answer if you could replicate a minimal example of what your problem is in the question.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this, using list comprehension:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]

# list comp. loops over each list in data (i)
# then appends every element j in i to a string
# end result is one string per row
pd.DataFrame([' '.join(str(j) for j in i) for i in data], columns=['Review'])
>>>   Review
    0  1 2 3
    1  4 5 6
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go.

```
import pandas as pd
data=[['a b'],['c d']] # assuming each sublist has reviews 

data=[ i[0] for i in data] # make one list 

df = pd.DataFrame({'review':data})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
 review
0    a b
1    c d
```